# After deploy in Nexus, the variables in POM.xml are not resolved?

Tags: maven, variables, pom.xml, nexus

I use Maven Multi-Modul, Jenkins builds and then deploy in Nexus...

I'm using in my Pom files many variables that I have defined in parent-pom part propertis

I would have after the build/deploy resolved the variables in Pom-Nexus.

I know that this is feasible, because I made a few years ago....

Comment: First why do you need properties in your parent ? For dependency versions?

Answer (score 4):

I think, i found it

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.sap.prd.mobile.ios.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>resolve-pom-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>resolve-pom-props</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>resolve-pom-props</goal>
            </goals>              
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: We have also used successfully https://github.com/paradoxical-io/resolved-pom-maven-plugin.

Comment: The posted `com.sap.prd.mobile.ios.maven.plugins` worked for me, but the second referenced, `paradoxical-io/resolved-pom-maven-plugin` did not replace ALL the versions, and it also generated a `target/resolved-pom.xml` rather than simply resolving in `target/pom.xml` so the modified file wasn't used in the `deploy` target.